# How to set app name and icon xamarin forms across platforms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Is there a quick way to set the app name and icon on xamarin.forms across platforms? I googled a lot but I haven't seen any way to do it in the shared project.

Comment: Fast answer: **No**. I don't recall Xamarin.Forms having the ability to set the icon from the shared project. Unless something changed 1year ago until now, you still need to do that for each platform alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Each platform has it's own rules about icon sizes.

Comment: How about the app name?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason said there is no way to do it. Especially you will understand it when you try to upload your app to stores. Every store has its own rules to upload an app. For example, to submit an app to Apple, you should have different sizes of an icon for every iPhone and iPad models, and Google has its own.

Comment: How about the app name?

Comment: In Android, change the Application Name of Android Manifest of Android project's property.
In iOS, change the Application name of iOS Application of iOS project's property.
@PaulaKristin